# llvm 3.9 ConstantExpr::getAsInstruction for Instruction::GetElementPtr get assertion

Tags: llvm, assert

I migrated from LLVM 3.6.1 to LLVM 3.9.0. In LLVMv3.6 this code execute fine, but in LLVMv3.9 I have assertion failure:

```
... include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:866: static llvm::GetElementPtrInst* llvm::GetElementPtrInst::Create(llvm::Type*, llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, const llvm::Twine&, llvm::Instruction*): Assertion `PointeeType == cast<PointerType>(Ptr->getType()->getScalarType())->getElementType()' failed.
```

My Code is:

```
pOperand = pStore->getValueOperand();

if(!pOperand) 
    return;

pConstExpr = dyn_cast<ConstantExpr>(pOperand);

if(!pConstExpr)  
    return; 

if(pConstExpr->getOpcode() == Instruction::GetElementPtr)
{
     pGEPInst = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(pConstExpr->getAsInstruction());  // Assertion !!!
     if(!pGEPInst) 
         return;
     ... other code ...
}
```

EDIT:

This problem appears only when the build type  of LLVM-3.9.0 is DEBUG. The RELEASE-build hasn't this problem!

Comment: Can you provide the IR?

Comment: The fact that it does not complain in release is just hiding a probable error, you'll get in trouble at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I found where I had a problem. It is my own mistake. In instruction GetElementPtrInst of LLVM-3.9.0 appeared argument "Type *PointeeType", but LLVM-3.6.1 it argument wasn't, and that was the my error.

When in LLVM-3.6.1 I generate LLVM IR from source file, I got IR-line:

```
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([14 x i8]* @.str1, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %2
```

in LLVM-3.9.0 this line:

```
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([14 x i8], [14 x i8]* @.str1, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %2
```

After this in both versions I change global variable @.str1 to @globstr1, and replace it everywhere in module. In LLVM-3.6.1 this line transform to:

```
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([17 x i8]* @globstr1, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %2
```

and worked fine, but in LLVM-3.9.0 this line transform to:

```
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([14 x i8], [17 x i8]* @globstr1, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %2
```

the ***Type [14 x i8]*** not changed and in this place occurred assertion failure.

EDIT:

This problem appears only when the build with ASSERTS (parameter -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1 for CMAKE. This parametr default is ON for DEBUG build). In RELEASE-build it doesn't appear because parametr DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS default is off (default for RELEASE build)!